# Linux vi arrow keys broken in insert mode

Tags: linux, vim, vi

My arrow keys don't work in vi in insert mode at home, they just each insert a newline and a capital letter, like 'A'.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I mean distribution of linux?

Comment: Do they work away from home ? :-)

Comment: Obviously, the solution is emacs. Obviously.

Comment: @Paul Nathan - If the solution is emacs, then I don't want to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I presume you're using vim as this is tagged as Linux. Try:

```
:set nocompatible
```

(You may want to configure your .vimrc with this by adding this command to it. Create a new .vimrc file if not already present in your home directory, run `echo $HOME` to check home directory path.)

Comment: Make sure you start vi with the command `vim` and not `vi`. Most of the advanced and useful features of `vim` are disabled by default unless you start it with `vim`.

Comment: @pts - only on broken systems.  Starting vim as vi on all of my boxes works just fine; however, there are some CentOS boxes I have used that demonstrate the behavior you are talking about.

Comment: Can somebody edit this answer to include what it would look like in a vimrc?

Comment: @Stephan Add `set nocompatible` on its own line in the .vimrc

Comment: On Ubuntu I solved this by simply installing vim (sudo apt install vim) from that moment on vi works fine with the arrow keys in insert mode. Edit: I see now this was already mentioned by Han below here.

Answer (score 88):

Ubuntu ships default with `vim-tiny`, which doesn't have all the bells and whistles that vim has.

Do a quick `sudo apt-get install vim` to get all the juicy features that everyone's talking about.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed in mint linux. By installing vim i was still able to start using "vi" and all the code highlighting was now enabled. What a fantastic piece of linux knowledge :)

Comment: This worked for my Raspberry Pi (Jessie Lite). I was experiencing this issue when I would secure shell into it, but now it is resolved entirely :-)

Answer (score 44):

`:set term=builtin_ansi`

fixed it for me. You can either paste that into vim while in escape mode, (bleep mode) or add it to the end of ~/.vimrc without the leading ":"

Comment: :set term=xterm might also work, (and easier to remember).

Comment: FYI `:set term=builtin_ansi` worked for me. `:set term=xterm` did not.

Comment: on one of my Linux boxes I use `export TERM=xterm` on the command line  before invoking vi and then `:set term=xterm` in vim 7.2 works for me

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!

Comment: This works to enable arrow key navigation but it completely killed all the color coding in the terminal.

Answer (score 18):

vi does not support arrow keys in insert mode. Use vim. Although your vi may just be a link to vim, it may be configured to behave like the "original" vi and thus disables the arrow keys. Just invoke vim directly.

Comment: Although this is not a solution, it is the best explanation for the behaviour (imo), making clear the difference between `vi` and `vim`. But on my box `vim` prints `command not found` :D

Comment: @DanFromGermany Maybe you have only a vi installed and not vim. Please try to install vim via the package manager of you Linux system if you'd like to use it.

Comment: `:set term=ansi` worked for me thanks [Raz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228199/611007). you say it 'does not support'. I am wondering did you say that because `vim-tiny` package of ubuntu -I're using- is different from vanilla `vi` or would term setting work in that too?

Answer (score 8):

Yet another variation:  this problem appeared for me after some .vimrc changes.  A concerted search eventually revealed that my clever re-mapping of ESC in normal mode was not a good idea.  Removing it solved the problem:

```
" this is NOT something you want in .vimrc:
" In normal mode, hitting Esc turns off search highlights:
nmap <ESC> :nohl<CR>  " Do NOT add this to .vimrc
```

Comment: I tried everything after experiencing this issue, and this was what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I looked everywhere. Any idea why remapping escape causes problems?

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that worked for me was ":set term=ansi"

Comment: This also seems to have worked for me using a Docker container.

Comment: This one worked for me too. I am using cmd.exe in windows and sshing into ubuntu using vagrant

Comment: @CodeCodeO-1-O-log-n so which side were you using `vi` on the windows or the ubuntu side? :)

Comment: On windows, I ran cmd.exe and then vagrant ssh into ubuntu server and then vi into the server. But later i started using Putty and I dont need to do that anymore and Putty is working great for me.

Comment: I've tried all three solutions and this is the only one that worked for me:
```set nocompatible
set term=ansi
set noesckeys```

Comment: Only needed the first 2:

Comment: I used: `set nocompatible` `set term=ansi` `set backspace=indent,eol,start`

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue with arrow keys, but when I used did that set nocp or nocompatible then my backspace didn't work correctly

for some reason when I installed vim with 
`sudo apt-get install vim`, vi didn't had any issues with arrows or backspace anymore

Answer (score 2):

In WSL integrated terminal on VS Code, update the package and install the full package of vim worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

However, to make the arrow key works when I use conemu I have to add `:set term=builtin_ansi` on `~/.vimrc`

```
echo ':set term=builtin_ansi' >> ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had an issue with arrow keys after switching over to use git in .vim.

I have installed this repo - https://github.com/sunaku/.vim

and after digging around for an hour, I found that AutoClose plugin
(which didn't like anyway) broke the arrow keys.

The plugin docs suggest that one should set set ttimeoutlen=100, but
that didn't work for me! (using urxvt+screen or urxvt, and even xterm)

So I removed the plugin at the end.

Answer (score 1):

To support vi and vim, I used the following as a minimum in my .vimrc file in my user's home folder (~):

```
set nocompatible
set term=ansi
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try 'noesckeys'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using vim inside Windows 8.1 with Cygwin.

Solution worked for me is, just run the following command in your Cygwin terminal:

```
cp vimrc_example.vim ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score -1):

In the command line write this:

```
EXINIT="set nocompatible"; export EXINIT
```

Comment: please add some (short) description of your solution