# Cannot use arrows in VI on some consoles

Tags: linux, console, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux vi arrow keys broken in insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812973/linux-vi-arrow-keys-broken-in-insert-mode)

When I use vi in some consoles, I can use the arrows normally. But in others if I press the up arrow, it prints an "A". I then have to press escape to use the arrows normally.

I'm guessing it's something in the terminal configuration. How do I fix this?

Comment: You could always learn to move cursor with hjkl as God intended. Works everywhere. Impress friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Vim instead of vi. I was forced to use vi at uni. It's crap.