# My Vim 7.3 does not behave the same way as Vim 7.1?

Tags: linux, text, vi, vim

I always wanted to ask this question but thought it was somehow my fault. I use Vim at two places: one in Ubuntu and the other in Cygwin.

```
Ubuntu: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1 (2007 May 12, compiled May  6 2008 16:24:07)
Cygwin: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 19 2010 13:06:02)
```

In 7.1, when I go into the `Insert` mode using `Esc-i`, I can use the arrow keys and use it as a normal text editor like nano. However, in the other version, 7.3, when I enter the `insert` mode, I can no longer use my arrow keys or space. When I hit any of them, I get characters like `C`, `D` etc. for arrow keys. I might be missing something here but am not sure why the discrepancy and if I can revert back to the way it was before. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a terminal issue.

Comment: Are you running the cygwin vim in a cmd shell, or the rxvt shell?

Comment: @Keith: I am using the mintty shell for cygwin

Comment: Try running it in the rxvt terminal.

Comment: @Keith: Tried it. Facing the same problem.

Comment: Hey @Legend, did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Usually doing `:set nocompatible` works: [Linux vi arrow keys broken in insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812973/linux-vi-arrow-keys-broken-in-insert-mode)

In this case I tried it out in cygwin and you I also needed `:set term=ansi` to get it to work.

So viraptor pretty much had it, except you want to set NOcompatible:

```
:set nocompatible
:set term=ansi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
:set compatible
:set term=ansi
```

(or other terminal - windows one might need "win32")

Comment: Hmm.. it is strange but nothing changes when I do that. When I set the terminal to ansi, however, it slows down drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you figured this out. Unfortunately I can't yet add this as a comment, so adding it as answer, try:

```
:set nocompatible
```

by itself -- did the trick  for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
set nocompatible
```

in file:
~/.exrc