# Docker Ubuntu image missing prompt, color and completion?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

If I create a new Docker image based from `ubuntu:14.04` image and run it with:

```
docker run -i --name="TEST" ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

then I will have a minimalistic Ubuntu with Bash running, but I won't get a prompt and the auto-completion for files/folders does not work. Also if I try to edit a file using `vi` then the terminal will corrupt everything shown on the screen, and arrows wont work either.

So how can I create a new image from ubuntu:14.04 where the 'normal' Bash-like functionality from a 'normal' terminal from the Ubuntu Desktop distribution is working so that I have the same colored prompt, auto-completion of files/folders are working and also vi works as expected?

**EDIT:** I'm running boot2docker on Windows if that makes any difference!?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing `-t` flag to allocate a pseudo-tty for your container:

`docker run -it --name="TEST" ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash`

Comment: Ohh... thanks! That added the prompt and some color-coding of files. However if I edit a file with `vi` then I can't use the arrow keys to go up/down/left/right.... do you know why?

Comment: Escape, : (colon), x (remove), dd (delete line) etc. works. Its just the arrow keys that does not do anything. Cursor simply stays where it is.

Comment: That has to do with `vi` itself, I think it doesn't have support for cursor movement using arrow keys, but using `h`, `j`, `k` and `l` instead. Install fully-fledged `vim` inside the container for that: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y vim`

Comment: I tried installing vim and even tried creating the file ~/.vimrc with content `set nocompatible` but arrow keys still does not work. The `h`, `j`, `k` and `l`keys works, but since I'm not an expert in vi I would rather have the arrow keys to navigate around the source.

Comment: Weird. It looks to me as if you're using some odd TERM configuration. Try this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell

Comment: what shows, in your container `echo $TERM` it should not be DUMB or such

Comment: No, it's `xterm`. I will see if I can use the `h`, `j`, `k` and `l` keys instead. Guess it's just a matter of training :-D

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? 
Whether you see $TERM is xterm or something else, 
:set nocompatible or :set term=builtin_ansi in vi(m) or in ~/.vimrc without the ':' in $HOME directory seem to work.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812973/linux-vi-arrow-keys-broken-in-insert-mode

And probably related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13817