# Arrow keys not working in vi/vim in remote ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, terminal, vi

I am trying to edit my python file in vi, but my arrow keys are not working.

```
 vim $HOME/.vimrc     -->   :set nocompatible
```

I tried **arrow keys** , **Home**, **Delete** and **End** keys in both vi and vim , but they are not working..

***vi x.py***

***vim x.py***

Comment: Good thing arrow keys are completely unnecessary in Vi. That aside, you should report how exactly are the keys not working (i.e. what exactly happens when you press them in command mode and insert mode), how you are logging into your remote terminal (from Mac using ssh...? from Windows using PuTTy...?), and what terminal the remote is set to.

Comment: I am using PuTTy for accessing my google cloud instance. I want to edit my python script , so without using arrow keys how can I move my cursor ?

Comment: "I am using PuTTy for accessing my google cloud instance". Your TERM environment variable is probably not set up correctly.

Comment: Sorry , but i didn't get u .. Could you please elaborate , what I should do?

Comment: Also, [this](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/putty-configuration/) might help with PuTTy terminal configuration. Possibly, [Solution 13 here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell) might also help. (Sorry, not the best with Windows.)

Comment: Ok , so this is a configuration issue with Putty , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow keys are useful when in insert mode. It may be that your vim installation is not a full one per [Linux vi arrow keys broken in insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812973/linux-vi-arrow-keys-broken-in-insert-mode) in which case follow the instructions in the answer by Han.

Comment: Comments in the original thread pointed to a different cause than any of the solutions on this link.